# List a number of copies per book

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, group-by

For a school project, I should do queries on this Library model.

I've done good so far, but now I'm stuck on this question: "List a number of copies per book".

Here's what've done and not working as it should:

```
SELECT liv_titulo, ( 
    SELECT count(exe_cod)
    FROM exemplar
    GROUP BY liv_cod
    ORDER BY COUNT(exe_cod) desc) Quantidade
FROM livro INNER JOIN exemplar USING (liv_cod);
```

Comment: have a look at the documentation. There are some examples there: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions046.htm#SQLRF00624. You do not need the subquery to get the count. You can, but it is complicates your query and will be less performant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technique you wanted to use is a *correlated subquery*:

- you need a `WHERE` clause in the subquery so it only takes into account the `liv_code` from the current row in the outer query
- no `GROUP BY` clause is needed in the subquery; it should return a *scalar value* (just one row and one column, that contains the count of matching rows from table `examplar`)
- there is no need for a `join` in the outer query

Code:

```
SELECT 
    liv_titulo, 
    ( 
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM exemplar e
        WHERE e.liv_cod = l.liv_cod  -- correlation
    ) Quantidade
FROM livro l;
```